# How to run snap daemon outside a container

Tags: virtual-machine, lxc, container, snap

It looks like snap programs (installed on ubuntu) are run instide VMs/containers created by Canonical (called multipass).

But what if my daemon needs access to the host filesystem, host system socket files, and needs to listen on a port? Is there a way to run a snap program as a systemctl daemon outside a container/VM and run in directly on the host machine?